# Get TFS build info during test run (in TFS team build)

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration, tfsbuild, tfs-alerts

We have a solution that is built and tested automatically by TFS after every check-in.

Is there a way i can get any build information programatically while the TFS is executing the integration tests?

For example: if a test fails, i need to know who requested the build to notify him via email with attached custom log files that my tests are creating.

Answer (score 2):

You can setup Alerts to automatically receive an email if a build fails (the email includes more details about the build).  In Visual Studio go to the Team Menu -> Project Alerts.

Comment: thank you. Well the built in TFS alerts are not enough for me. My integration tests are building some custom log files and must send them to the person who broke the build. I see no way attaching the custom logs to the basic TFS alerts.

Comment: Who triggered the build is shown in the build summary. If you build after check in, it will be that person. A bug will be raised. Devs should subscribe to their own builds, they will then know the outcome of their change. The email will have the drop folder linked. Put your output logs in there

Comment: The team is mostly working from home and have no easy access to the drop directory. That is why i need to attach a custom mail with logs attached. Perhaps what i am asking for is possible with environmental variables?